# How to check some information from firebase cloud in flutter like a "roomName" and "roomPassword"?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i want to check some information from firebase collection. In my cloud firestore, i have a **roomName** and **roomPassword** and i am getting this data from user and checking with my firestore. So I created a class and writed the checker function. But it doesnt work. I am trying to find a problem for a 2 days. Maybe my method can be wrong if so you can give another method.
i need the help..
Thanks..

**My Cloud firestore**

[Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdulj.png)

**My class and function**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class RoomService {
  final String roomName;
  final String roomPassword;
  RoomService({this.roomPassword, this.roomName});

  final CollectionReference _productCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('product');

  Future<void> createRoom(String roomName, String roomPassword) async {
    return await _productCollection
        .doc(roomName)
        .set({'roomName': roomName, 'roomPassword': roomPassword});
  }

  Future joinRoom(String roomName, String roomPassword) async {
    _productCollection.doc(roomName).get().then((getData) {
      try {
        if ((getData.data()['roomName'] == roomName) &&
            (getData.data()['roomPassword'] == roomPassword)) {
          print("works");
          return true;
        } else {
          print("some error");
          return false;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        print(error.toString());
        return null;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**I am calling from here**

```
   import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:cool_alert/cool_alert.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';
import 'package:tekstil/screens/chooser.dart';
import 'package:tekstil/services/room.dart';
import 'package:tekstil/shared/alert_dialog.dart';
import 'package:tekstil/shared/text.dart';
import 'package:tekstil/shared/context_extension.dart';
import 'package:tekstil/shared/textfield.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  RoomService _service = RoomService();

  String roomName;
  String roomPassword;

  getRoomName(roomName1) {
    this.roomName = roomName1;
  }

  getRoomPassword(roomPassword1) {
    this.roomPassword = roomPassword1;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.business_center_rounded,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (_) => AlertDialogWidget(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
                // backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                title: Text("Şirket'e Katıl"),
                content: Container(
                  height: context.dynamicHeight(0.15),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: TextFieldWidget(
                          hint: "ID",
                          onChanged: (String roomName1) {
                            getRoomName(roomName1);
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Spacer(),
                      Expanded(
                        child: TextFieldWidget(
                          hint: "Sifre",
                          onChanged: (String roomPassword1) {
                            getRoomPassword(roomPassword1);
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                actions: [
                  FlatButton(
                  //**i am calling that function from here**
                    child: Text("Katıl"),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      dynamic _getData =
                          _service.joinRoom(roomName, roomPassword);
                      if (_getData == true) {
                        Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      } else {
                        print("false döndü");
                        Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                            context,
                             MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Chooser()),
                            (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
                      }
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_rounded),
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (_) => AlertDialogWidget(
                  // backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  title: Text("Şirket Kur"),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
                  content: Container(
                    height: context.dynamicHeight(0.20),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextFieldWidget(
                            hint: "ID",
                            onChanged: (String roomName1) {
                              getRoomName(roomName1);
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextFieldWidget(
                            hint: "Sifre",
                            onChanged: (String roomPassword1) {
                              getRoomPassword(roomPassword1);
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),

                  actions: [
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text("Kur"),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        // final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

                        // final User user = auth.currentUser;

                        await RoomService().createRoom(roomName, roomPassword);
                        CoolAlert.show(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                          confirmBtnColor: Colors.black,
                          confirmBtnText: "Tamam",
                          onConfirmBtnTap: () {
                            Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Chooser()),
                                (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
                          },
                          title: "Başarılı",
                          context: context,
                          type: CoolAlertType.success,
                          text: "Oda başarıyla kuruldu",
                        );
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          )
        ],
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: AppBarText1("Anasayfa"),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('product').snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }

          return ListView(
            children: snapshot.data.docs.map((documentSnapshot) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Slidable(
                    actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
                    actionExtentRatio: 0.25,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: ListTile(
                        trailing: LabelText("Ürün Aşaması: \n   " +
                                documentSnapshot["productStatus"] ??
                            ""),
                        isThreeLine: true,
                        hoverColor: Colors.black,
                        onTap: () {
                          // print("basildi.");
                        },
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.indigoAccent,
                          child: Icon(Icons.storage_rounded),
                          foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        title: LabelText(documentSnapshot["productName"] ?? ""),
                        subtitle: Text(documentSnapshot["productCode"] ?? ""),
                      ),
                    ),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      IconSlideAction(
                          caption: 'Archive',
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          icon: Icons.archive,
                          onTap: () {}),
                    ],
                    secondaryActions: <Widget>[
                      IconSlideAction(
                          caption: 'Delete',
                          color: Colors.red,
                          icon: Icons.delete,
                          onTap: () {}),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }).toList(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell what is the error.

Comment: there's no error. it is going on the else statement and print("some error");    :/

Comment: try my answer added below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle something like this is to get the doc, then compare fields, like this:

```
Future joinRoom(String roomName, String roomPassword) async {
final Map<String, dynamic> roomData = 
  await _productCollection.doc(roomName).get().then((getData) => getData.data());
if (roomData['roomPassword'] == roomPassword) {
   //do something
 } else {
  return null;
 }

}
```

Comment: i am getting this error  in your code: "A value of type 'Future<Map<String, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Map<String, dynamic>'."

Comment: Forgot to put the await in front of the _productCollection.  Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Future joinRoom(String roomName, String roomPassword) async {
DocumentSnapshot doc=await Firestore.instance.collection('product').doc(roomName).get();
          try {
            if ((doc.data()['roomName'] == roomName) &&
                (doc.data()['password'] == roomPassword)) {
              print("works");
              return true;
            } else {
              print("some error");
              return false;
            }
          } catch (error) {
            print(error.toString());
            return null;
          }
      }
```

Comment: doesn't work  it's going on the else statement again :/

Comment: can you print the value of doc.data['roomName']

Comment: where should i print the value of doc.data['roomName'] ?

Comment: before try block and have changed my code a bit try with the new one

Comment: in your code, there was a this error: "the operator ' ' isn't defined for the type 'map string dynamic function()'" so i just added the "()" in (doc.data()['roomName'] but still not working . And before try block, i print( doc.data()['roomName'] ) and its worked :(

Comment: are you getting the value by print statement? and in my new code i am not using the collection reference you declared above i have declared it in the function bcoz maybe collection reference declared outside is not getting executed.

Comment: yes, in your changed code, i just put "print(doc.data()['roomName']);" before the try blocks and it's printed. But again, it's going on the else statement. So it's not work.

Comment: print the roomName, roomPassword you are passing to the function before try block and the value you getting from firebase are all four having value. and remove that try block too for once

Comment: as you say, i put"" print(doc.data()['roomName']);
    print(doc.data()['roomPassword']);  "" before the try blocks. The roomName is working but the roomPassword returned null. I dont know why. roomName is ok but it's not printed roomPassword. :/

Comment: ah it worked we were doing silly mistake you have saved the field as password not roomPassword have update the code pls check.